# Ubuntu on Asus laptop doesn't recognise Intel SSD

Tags: system-installation, disk

SSD: Intel 335
Laptop: ASUS X555LD-XX852H
Problem: My brother replaced the original HDD with a the SSD and tried to install Ubuntu using a flash startup disk. However, the SSD isn't listed as an option and it doesn't appear in Disks (gnome-disks).
Additional info: The SSD originally didn't appear in setup/bios, but switching CSM mode made it bootable and recognized in setup.

My brother has already returned the laptop, but it isn't the first time this happened with Asus laptop so I'm asking for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Place your SSD in a working windows computer. Download and run the current INTEL firmware upgrade on your SSD and try the installation on your laptop again.

Comment: The Intel SSD update tool (5/5/2015 version) says the firmware is up to date.